# subscriptions on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with three fields `active`, `start_suscription`, `end_suscription`, `active is boolean` and i**f it is true is because the subscription is not finished**, my question is how do I make rails automatically change it to false` when the subscription ends, in django it is very easy But I'm just starting with rails and I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to not use another column to "cache" an information that can be easily computed:

If you remove the column `active`, you can determine if a single record is active by defining the instance method `active?`:

```
# in your model
def active?(as_of_date = Date.current)
  (start_suscription..end_suscription).include?(as_of_date)
end
# usage
instance = YourModel.new(start_suscription: Date.yesterday, end_suscription: Date.tomorrow)
instance.active? # => true
instance.active?(Date.current + 1.week) # => false
```

To get all active records, make a scope:

```
scope :active, -> (as_of_date = Date.current) { where('? BETWEEN start_suscription AND end_suscription', as_of_date) }
# usage
YourModel.active
YourModel.active(Date.yesterday)
```

---

If you want to stick with your caching column (which I strongly advice against), you will need a worker (something triggered every X amount of time) to go grab all records that are now inactive and update their `active` column.

Answer (score 0):

If active is a database field, you can create a callback in your subscription model like

```
before_save :set_active

def set_active
self.active = self.start_subscription >= Date.today and self.end_suscription <= Date.today
end
```

Like mr yoshii says active should not be a database field. If it is, and you dont want to change it you should touch the record at every request or in a daily task.

Comment: So if I make a suscription in the future, I will have my `active` attribute set to `active` even though it has not started yet?